# Giving a different id to each child of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, attributes, children

First question ever, new to programming. I'll try to be as concise as possible.

What I want to do is to create a bunch of children inside a selected div and give each of them specific html content (from a predefined array) and a different id to each child.

I created this loop for the effect:

```
Game.showOptions = function() {
    var i = 0;
    Game.choiceElement.html("");
    for (i=0; i<Game.event[Game.state].options.length; i++) {
        Game.choiceElement.append(Game.event[Game.state].options[i].response);
        Game.choiceElement.children()[i].attr("id","choice1");    
    }
};
```

Using the predefined values of an array:

```
Game.event[0] = { text: "Hello, welcome.",
                      options: [{response: "<a><p>1. Um, hello...</p></a>"},
                                {response: "<a><p>2. How are you?</p></a>"}]
                };
```

This method does not seem to be working, because the loop stops running after only one iteration. I sincerely have no idea why. If there is a completely different way of getting what I need, I'm all ears.

If I define the id attribute of each individual p inside the array, it works, but I want to avoid that.

The idea is creating a fully functional algorithm for dialogue choices (text-based rpg style) that would work with a predefined array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'd be assigning the same id to every child you append. perhaps `"choice" + i` would make more sense?

Comment: if you're using jQuery already, is there a reason you don't want to just select the different child div's via the CSS3 child-selectors?

Comment: Marc B -  You are correct, for now I just wanted to make the loop work, but thanks for pointing it out!

Abernasty - I appologize but I don't know how to answer that question! I'm afraid I have to learn much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your loop as I see it could be in a couple different places. Here are three things you should check for, and that I am assuming you have but just didn't show us...

Is `Game` defined as an object?

```
var Game = {};
```

Is `event` defined as an array?

```
Game.event = new Array();
```

Is `Game.state` returning a number, and the appropriate number at that? I imagine this would be a little more dynamic then I have written here, but hopefully you'll get the idea.

```
Game.state = 0;
```

Now assuming all of the above is working properly...

**Use `eq(i)` instead of `[i]`.**

```
for (var i = 0; i<Game.event[Game.state].options.length; i++) {
    Game.choiceElement.append(Game.event[Game.state].options[i].response);
    Game.choiceElement.children().eq(i).attr("id","choice" + (i + 1));
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KPpLA/3/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, all variables were approriately declared as you mentioned. That little eq() tweak does indeed solve the problem!

The loop now runs appropriately.